# Loading screen gets stuck while processing HTTP request

Tags: javascript, html, css, loader

I have a javascript code that gets some content from another web page to display (using HTTP GET). After some tests, realizing the process takes some time, I've decided to add a loading animation that runs until the code ends to get the content from the different webpage. As supposed, the loading animation disappears when the content is fully loaded. 
My only problem is that when the process starts, the loading animation gets stuck. That happens even after I defined the process as asynchronous. This is my code:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var response = httpGet("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/akduztal2rq");
  }, 2000); // the GET method executes 2 seconds after the loading animation is loaded
});
async function httpGet(theUrl) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  await xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
  await xmlhttp.send();
  var r = xmlhttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = r;
  document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/yqekxmddlvd">
</head>

<body>
  <svg version="1.1" id="preloader" x="0px" y="0px" width="240px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 240 120"> <!--The animation -->
    
    
          <style type="text/css" >
            <![CDATA[
    
            #plug,
            #socket { fill:#D9E4E8 }
    
            #loop-normal { fill: none; stroke: #D9E4E8; stroke-width: 12 }
            #loop-offset { display: none }
    
            ]]>
          </style>
    
          <path id="loop-normal" class="st1" d="M120.5,60.5L146.48,87.02c14.64,14.64,38.39,14.65,53.03,0s14.64-38.39,0-53.03s-38.39-14.65-53.03,0L120.5,60.5
                                                L94.52,87.02c-14.64,14.64-38.39,14.64-53.03,0c-14.64-14.64-14.64-38.39,0-53.03c14.65-14.64,38.39-14.65,53.03,0z">
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" attributeType="XML"
                     from="500, 50"  to="450 50"
                     begin="0s" dur="2s"
                     repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" attributeType="XML"
                     from="-40"  to="-540"
                     begin="0s" dur="2s"
                     repeatCount="indefinite"/>  
          </path>
    
          <path id="loop-offset" d="M146.48,87.02c14.64,14.64,38.39,14.65,53.03,0s14.64-38.39,0-53.03s-38.39-14.65-53.03,0L120.5,60.5
                                    L94.52,87.02c-14.64,14.64-38.39,14.64-53.03,0c-14.64-14.64-14.64-38.39,0-53.03c14.65-14.64,38.39-14.65,53.03,0L120.5,60.5
                                    L146.48,87.02z"/>
    
          <path id="socket" d="M7.5,0c0,8.28-6.72,15-15,15l0-30C0.78-15,7.5-8.28,7.5,0z"/>  
    
          <path id="plug" d="M0,9l15,0l0-5H0v-8.5l15,0l0-5H0V-15c-8.29,0-15,6.71-15,15c0,8.28,6.71,15,15,15V9z"/>
    
          <animateMotion
                         xlink:href="#plug"
                         dur="2s"
                         rotate="auto"
                         repeatCount="indefinite"
                         calcMode="linear"
                         keyTimes="0;1"    
                         keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1">
            <mpath xlink:href="#loop-normal"/>
          </animateMotion>
    
          <animateMotion             
                         xlink:href="#socket"
                         dur="2s"
                         rotate="auto"
                         repeatCount="indefinite"
                         calcMode="linear"
                         keyTimes="0;1"
                         keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1">
            <mpath xlink:href="#loop-offset"/>
          </animateMotion>  
        </svg>
  <div id="h">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

as you can see, the svg tag is responsible for generating the animation, and the setTimeout function makes the HTTP GET method executes 2 seconds after the loading animation is loaded. anyway, in the first 2 seconds the animation works fine, but after 2 seconds when the GET process starts, it gets stuck. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You're getting a network error, meaning that the code after `xmlhttp.open` is not being reached, there are several ways to solve this, but the easiest is using try/catch

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to access resources from a source domain which is not the same as yours. Long story short the reason for that is about `CORS`.

In order to make possible this kind of requests, the response headers should contain the following headers:

`Accept-Control-Allow-Origin: yourdomain.com 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: GET`

**More about:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Tried it, and the opposite happened, the content of the webpage i'm using in GET got blocked, so it didn't work. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I noticed you are using async/await on XMLHttpRequest.
I don't think they return promises to be used with await.

If you want to use async/await try using the fetch api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5d249d172f0000736f241b00', true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('hi 1')
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a network error, so Javascript is raising an exception and the code where you remove the loading is never reached, try this :

```
async function httpGet(theUrl) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  try{
    await xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
    await xmlhttp.send();
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }finally {
    var r = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = r;
    document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Learn more about try/catch/finally : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_try_catch.asp

It's a very common pattern to use the `finally` block to remove loadings, since you always want to remove it either it failed or suceeded.

Comment: didn't work. in my server i'm not getting a network error, the loading animation gets stuck and then it loads the content of the webpage. So generally I'm trying to execute GET while the loading animation is still running. any more ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
   
  setTimeout(function() {
    var response = httpGet("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  }, 3000);
function httpGet(theUrl) {    
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'theUrl', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onload = function () {
    var r = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = r;
    document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/yqekxmddlvd">
</head>

<body>
  <svg version="1.1" id="preloader" x="0px" y="0px" width="240px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 240 120"> <!--The animation -->
    
    
          <style type="text/css" >
            <![CDATA[
    
            #plug,
            #socket { fill:#D9E4E8 }
    
            #loop-normal { fill: none; stroke: #D9E4E8; stroke-width: 12 }
            #loop-offset { display: none }
    
            ]]>
          </style>
    
          <path id="loop-normal" class="st1" d="M120.5,60.5L146.48,87.02c14.64,14.64,38.39,14.65,53.03,0s14.64-38.39,0-53.03s-38.39-14.65-53.03,0L120.5,60.5
                                                L94.52,87.02c-14.64,14.64-38.39,14.64-53.03,0c-14.64-14.64-14.64-38.39,0-53.03c14.65-14.64,38.39-14.65,53.03,0z">
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" attributeType="XML"
                     from="500, 50"  to="450 50"
                     begin="0s" dur="2s"
                     repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" attributeType="XML"
                     from="-40"  to="-540"
                     begin="0s" dur="2s"
                     repeatCount="indefinite"/>  
          </path>
    
          <path id="loop-offset" d="M146.48,87.02c14.64,14.64,38.39,14.65,53.03,0s14.64-38.39,0-53.03s-38.39-14.65-53.03,0L120.5,60.5
                                    L94.52,87.02c-14.64,14.64-38.39,14.64-53.03,0c-14.64-14.64-14.64-38.39,0-53.03c14.65-14.64,38.39-14.65,53.03,0L120.5,60.5
                                    L146.48,87.02z"/>
    
          <path id="socket" d="M7.5,0c0,8.28-6.72,15-15,15l0-30C0.78-15,7.5-8.28,7.5,0z"/>  
    
          <path id="plug" d="M0,9l15,0l0-5H0v-8.5l15,0l0-5H0V-15c-8.29,0-15,6.71-15,15c0,8.28,6.71,15,15,15V9z"/>
    
          <animateMotion
                         xlink:href="#plug"
                         dur="2s"
                         rotate="auto"
                         repeatCount="indefinite"
                         calcMode="linear"
                         keyTimes="0;1"    
                         keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1">
            <mpath xlink:href="#loop-normal"/>
          </animateMotion>
    
          <animateMotion             
                         xlink:href="#socket"
                         dur="2s"
                         rotate="auto"
                         repeatCount="indefinite"
                         calcMode="linear"
                         keyTimes="0;1"
                         keySplines="0.42, 0, 0.58, 1">
            <mpath xlink:href="#loop-offset"/>
          </animateMotion>  
        </svg>
  <div id="h">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```